# Update UILabel from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save/load some data for my game (in this case, the # of tips the player has available to them). If they are playing the game for the first time, they get 10 tips to start with, otherwise, it will load the number of tips they had before they last quit the game. My issue is that when starting the game for the first time, I am setting the number of tips to 10 but the UILabel is displaying 0.

These here are my save and load methods:

```
- (void)saveSettings
{
    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [settings setInteger:self.tipCount forKey:@"tipCount"];
}

- (void)loadSettings
{
    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![settings boolForKey:@"userDefaultsSet"])
    {
        [settings setBool:1 forKey:@"userDefaultsSet"];
        [settings setInteger:10 forKey:@"tipCount"];
        self.tipCount = 10;
    } else {
        self.tipCount = [settings integerForKey:@"tipCount"];
    }    
}
```

And this here is how I am updating my label:

```
- (void)updateLabel
{
    Quiz* sharedQuiz = [Quiz sharedInstance];

    self.statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tips Remaining: %d", [sharedQuiz tipCount]];
}
```

Any help that can point me in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: After setting, `- synchronize` or wait a minute. Persistence doesn't happen instantly.

Comment: from where you are getting data from NSUserDefaults?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833907/adding-to-a-previously-saved-nsuserdefaults-in-xcode/15834362#15834362

Comment: Thank you, the synchronize solved part of my issue. After doing that, the debugger will tell me that tipCount is indeed 10. That being said, my label is still displaying a 0 so I am not sure where to go from here. I've followed the program through the debugger and everything seems to be running as it should be with all the right values.

Answer (score 0):

Here i would like add few things to your question as precautions, it might be so, you already have been taken that care but still i am trying to say you see below.

Check whether you are calling `loadSetting` method Before calling any other method (`saveSettings` method and `updateLabel` method) by which you want to display some information.look you have not set any value to tips count besides from that single method(`loadSetting`) if that method not caling it means you are getting this `0 number` on `UILabel`.so you should take care of this single thing whether you have properly called `loadSetting` method before showing the tips count to the user over the `UILabbel`.since after looking into your code it seems u that you did everything in correct way as you should have done.

You can check this out but setting some break point at required place and check out the main reason behind it.

I hope it may helps you and could give any idea so that you can get some help form above

Comment: I have done as you suggested, and, combined with the answers above, I was able to get the 0 updated to a 10, but only in the debugger. For some reason my UILabel is still not updating itself even though the variable itself is 10 when the update line is called.

Comment: @user1843954 i m pretty Sure that there is no issue in this part of code you shown here in SO.Check whether you have created `shared(singleton) Quiz class` properly or not.try to have some similar search how to create singleton class in ios sdk.don't if you already know ,but still you should check again your singleton class